# how do I update the key once its found in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a data like this

```
response = [{'startdata': 'Aug 24, 2022 10:37:50 PM', 'enddata': 'Aug 24, 2022 10:37:50 PM', 'province': 'Mashonaland_Central', 'district': 'Guruve', 'on_consent': '', 'meta': ''}]


data_mod = ["startdata", "enddata"]
```

need to check data_mod fields and if the key is present in the response variable I need to update it otherwise just ignore it.

what I'm doing

```
for data in response_json:
        try:
            dateformat_in = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
            dateformat_out = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"
            data["starttime"] = datetime.strptime(data["starttime"], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)
            data["endtime"] = datetime.strptime(data["endtime"], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)
            data["CompletionDate"] = datetime.strptime(data["CompletionDate"], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)
            data["SubmissionDate"] = datetime.strptime(data["SubmissionDate"], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)
            yield data
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    return data
```

But this is not working for me. need some help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question.

To update a key in a dictionary :

```
d = {"key1" : "valKey1"}

# Update the value of key1
d["key1"] = "updatedValueKey1"

print(d)
```

> {"key1" : "updatedValueKey1"}

Comment: Thanks but this I already know. my use-case is different

Comment: It was not at all clear in your first message.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like
`response[i] = datetime.strptime(response[i], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)`.The original statement doesn't change the value it passes.

Comment: THis is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

well, you can refresh the keys int the dict going across the list data_mod

```py
for key in data_mod:
    response[key]=new_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you apply proper date format. 
Example:

```py
dateformat_in = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
dateformat_out = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

for d in response:
    for key in data_mod:
        if key in d:
            d[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(d[key], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)
        
print(response)
```

Using a function: Your function should return response_json
**Note:** Make sure `data_mod` contains the right `key` names

```py
import datetime

response = [{'startdata': 'Aug 24, 2022 10:37:50 PM', 'enddata': 'Aug 24, 2022 10:37:50 PM', 'province': 'Mashonaland_Central', 'district': 'Guruve', 'on_consent': '', 'meta': ''}]

def update_date_format(response_json):
    data_mod = ["startdata", "enddata", "CompletionDate", "SubmissionDate"]
    
    dateformat_in = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
    dateformat_out = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    
    for data in response_json:
        for key in data_mod:
            if key in data:
                data[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[key], dateformat_in).strftime(dateformat_out)
            
    return response_json
    
response = update_date_format(response)
print(response)
```

Output:

```
[{'startdata': '2022-08-24 22:37:50', 'enddata': '2022-08-24 22:37:50', 'province': 'Mashonaland_Central', 'district': 'Guruve', 'on_consent': '', 'meta': ''}]
```

Comment: I have only shared one piece of data. It can have thousand of data like that in response. How will that work?

Comment: The code will still work with list of multiple dicts. I edited the answer by making it straight forward following your code pattern so you could have a better understanding, but it's basically the same with the previous answer.

Comment: somehow this is still not working for me. So I have changed the description to what I was doing before and how can I make that better?

Comment: What do you mean is not working? any error or undesired output? I will add another approach using function.